# Use matplotlib plot and PYsimpleGUI in pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pycharm, pysimplegui

I'm trying to add a plot to my GUI window.

the plot code is :

```
df.groupby(['zigzag', 'speed']).size().unstack().plot.bar()
```

and this is my GUI so far:

```
layout = [[sg.Text('Welcome', font='Thoma', size=(14, 1), justification='center')],
          [sg.Text('Please Upload Database:')],
          [sg.Text('File:', size=(8, 1)), sg.Input(key='file_input'), sg.FileBrowse(key="-IN-")],
          [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]]

window = sg.Window('Welcome', layout)

while True:
    event, vals = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Cancel"):
        break
    elif event == "Submit":
        file = vals["-IN-"]
        if file is not None:
            try:
                df = pd.read_csv(file)
                print(df)
                columns_list, unique_columns = column_list(df)
                window.close()
                layout2 = [
                    [sg.Text('Welcome', font='Thoma', size=(14, 1), justification='center')],
                    [sg.Text(' ')],
                    [sg.Button('OK'), sg.Cancel()]
                ]
                window2 = sg.Window('Choose', layout2, size=(500, 300), grab_anywhere=True)

                while True:
                    e, vals = window2.read()
                    if e == sg.WIN_CLOSED or e == 'Cancel':  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
                        break

                    elif e == 'OK':
                        df.groupby(['zigzag', 'speed']).size().unstack().plot()
                        window2.close()
```

the plot is supposed to be at the second window.

how can I show a plot on the GUI window?

Comment: Please share your GUI code.

Comment: There're 13 Demo scripts, Demo_Matplotlib_XXX.py, in https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/tree/master/DemoPrograms